# Como transformar essa query para lavarel?

Tags: php, lavarel

Tenho uma query e preciso transformar ela em código de lavarel.

Não tenho menor ideia de como fazer.

```
select DISTINCT (
    SELECT distinct
    products.name
    FROM
    products 
    join topics on topics.product_id = products.id ) AS product

from 
contents
join content_topics on content_topics.content_id = contents.id
join topics b on b.id = content_topics.topic_id 
where contents.id = 778;
```

Esse content.id vai ser o $request->id

```
public function listProduct(Request $request){
        if(isset($request->id)){
            $data = ??
        }
    }
```

Comment: Gabriel de qual tabela é o from, content ou products?

Comment: Da tabela contents

Comment: Você já rodou essa query no banco? funcionou?

Comment: sim, essa query funciona

Comment: Já entendi, vou editar a minha resposta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acesse a documentação do Laravel para aprender mais sobre a classe DB [Query](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/queries)

Existem muitas formas de fazer isso, a mais simples é com db select:

```
$data = DB::select("select DISTINCT (
            SELECT distinct
            products.name
            FROM
            products
            join topics on topics.product_id = products.id ) AS product

        from
        contents
        join content_topics on content_topics.content_id = contents.id
        join topics b on b.id = content_topics.topic_id
        where contents.id = 778")
        ->get();
```

Forma normal:

```
$data = DB::table('contents')
    ->selectRaw("select DISTINCT (
        SELECT distinct
        products.name
        FROM
        products
        join topics on topics.product_id = products.id ) AS product")
    ->join('content_topics','content_topics.content_id','=','contents.id')
    ->join('topics','topics.id','=','content_topics.topic_id')
    ->where('contents.id',$request->id)
    ->get();
```

Comment: Ambas as suas duas formas me da erro, a primeira com erro de get e a segunda erro de query

Comment: A query que gera funciona perfeitamente D; @Glenys Mitchell

Comment: Qual erro que dá?

Comment: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT DISTINCT (SELECT DISTINCT products.name FROM products JOIN topics ON topi' at line 1

Comment: (SQL: select SELECT DISTINCT (SELECT DISTINCT products.name FROM products JOIN topics ON topics.product_id = products.id ) AS product from `contents` inner join `content_topics` on `content_topics`.`content_id` = `contents`.`id` inner join `topics` on `topics`.`id` = `content_topics`.`topic_id` where `contents`.`id` = 778)"

Comment: OS dois erros são de banco =( a sua query deve ter algum erro.

Comment: Não mano, a query funciona perfeitamente

Comment: Entendi o porque, quando tu coloca o selectRaw, ele já joga um "select" na sua query, ai ele tava interpretando o SQL como select select

Comment: Fiz uma correção na segunda

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104441/discussion-between-gabrielfalieri-and-glenys-mitchell).

Comment: Ahhhhhh verdade, realmente não precisa.

Comment: Olha o chat la meu caro

Comment: Basta colocar o request conforme coloquei no chat

Answer (score 0):

Como o Glenys comento existem varias formas de se fazer a query, vou dar uma sugestão usando o Eloquent em vez da Facade DB.

```
$query = Model::query();
$query->where(function($q){
$q->select('*')->distinct()->from('tabela')->get();
});

$query->join('tabel.id','=','outratabel.id');
$query->where('contents.id','778')
$query->paginate(15);
```

Como o amigo aconselho de uma olhada no Eloquent